# blackberry add search field in list field

Tags: blackberry

I want to add an Search Box in list Field. When i Enter a letter, then it will show the names starting with the letter 'A' ,  and so on. How its done ?. Iam using Vector to save the facebook friends list and di[image]splay it. Its not a normal list.

```
Vector box1 = new Vector();
for(int i=0;i<splash.vector.size();i++){

    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)splash.vector.elementAt(i);

    String name=co_vec.getSender_name();
    String id=co_vec.getSender_id();
    //Dialog.alert(""+name);

     box = new CheckboxField(" "+name , checked, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
               graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
              super.paint(graphics);
            }
         };

         box1.addElement(box);
        // box.setMargin(6, 0, 0, 4);
         vfm.add(box);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an autocomplete field which will work on device OS 5.0 onwards. If you want your app to work on devices 4.5Os onwards , let me know and i will update the code

```
 Vector box1 = new Vector(); 
 Enumeration iterator = vector.elements();
        int i = 0;
        final Object[] objs = new Object[v.size()];
        while (iterator.hasMoreElements()) {
            objs[i] = (String) iterator.nextElement();
            i++;
        }
        BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
        filterList.setMinimumRefreshInterval(250);
        filterList.addDataSet(1, objs, "names",
                BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
        AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(
                filterList, AutoCompleteField.LIST_STATIC);  
        add(autoCompleteField);
```

This code will list all the strings in the vector and as you type,filter the results.

If you want to draw Check box you can over ride `public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g,int index, int y, int width)` and draw your own custom checkbox

To create an autocompletefield for OS4.5 onwards use the following code.

```
 Vector box1 = new Vector(); 
// Create an instance of our SortedReadableList class. 
        MySortedReadableList mySortedReadableList= new MySortedReadableList (box1);

        // Add our list to a KeywordFilterField object.
        KeywordFilterField _keywordFilterField = new KeywordFilterField();
        _keywordFilterField.setCallback(new ListFieldCallback() {

            public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics g,
                    int index, int y, int width) { 
                            super.drawListRow(listField, g,
                    index, y, width);
            }

            public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {
                if (index >= 0 && index < box1.size()) {
                    return _keywordFilterField.getResultList().getAt(index);
                }
                return null;
            }

            public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {
                return Display.getWidth();
            }

            public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix,
                    int start) {
                return listField.indexOfList(prefix, start);
            }
        });
        _keywordFilterField.setSourceList(mySortedReadableList,
                mySortedReadableList);

        // We're providing a customized edit field for
        // the KeywordFilterField.
        CustomKeywordField customSearchField = new CustomKeywordField();
        customSearchField.setPadding(8, 12, 8, 12);
        _keywordFilterField.setKeywordField(customSearchField);

        // Add our KeywordFilterField to the screen and push the screen
        // onto the stack.
        add(_keywordFilterField.getKeywordField());
        add(_keywordFilterField);
```

definition of MySortedReadableList

```
    class MySortedReadableList extends SortedReadableList implements KeywordProvider {
public MySortedReadableList (Vector box1) {
    super(new MySortedReadableListComparator()); 
    loadFrom(box1.elements());
}

void addElement(Object element) {
    doAdd(element);
}

public String[] getKeywords(Object element) {
    if (element instanceof String) {
        return StringUtilities.stringToWords(element.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

final static class MySortedReadableListComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Cannot compare null contacts");
        }
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
}
```

}

And now the CustomKeywordField

```
     /**
 * Inner Class: A custom keyword input field for the KeywordFilterField. We
 * want to prevent a save dialog from being presented to the user when
 * exiting the application as the ability to persist data is not relevent to
 * this application. We are also using the paint() method to customize the
 * appearance of the cursor in the input field.
 */
final static class CustomKeywordField extends BasicEditField {
    // Contructor
    CustomKeywordField() {
        // Custom style.
        super(USE_ALL_WIDTH | NON_FOCUSABLE | NO_LEARNING | NO_NEWLINE);

        setLabel("Search: ");
        setFont(boldTextFont);
    }

    /**
     * Intercepts ESCAPE key.
     * 
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.component.TextField#keyChar(char,int,int)
     */
    protected boolean keyChar(char ch, int status, int time) {
        switch (ch) {
        case Characters.ESCAPE:
            // Clear keyword.
            if (super.getTextLength() > 0) {
                setText("");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.keyChar(ch, status, time);
    }

    /**
     * Overriding super to add custom painting to our class.
     * 
     * @see net.rim.device.api.ui.Field#paint(Graphics)
     */
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(fontColor);
        graphics.setFont(boldTextFont);
        super.paint(graphics);

        // Draw caret.
        getFocusRect(new XYRect());
        drawFocus(graphics, true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it should work on 4.5 onwords. i need it same as the image shown above.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Check that. It doesnt have check box field, but just strings of names.

Comment: i need the checkbox also. without checkbox, i cant select morethan one item. So how to add the checkbox ?