# Searching in a list field containing checkboxes

Tags: search, blackberry, checkbox, checkboxlist, listfield

I want to implement similar functionality as in an address book of any android device with an addition of checkboxes in the list. But I want to implement it in BlackBerry and the support has to be given from **OS 4.5+**.

The screen should contain a search text field for searching names. Below the text box should be a list field with checkboxes with the names.

As I type in the search field, with every letter added or deleted, my list should show the relevant names and I should be able to check or uncheck the names. Also when i type next name, the one checked before should remain checked. At the end, i want all the checked contacts to be stored in a vector.

Comment: create new vector and put all the checked items there. then at last, compare all the two vectors and update

Comment: Have you tried the OS 4.5 solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8911296/119114)?  I'm not saying it works (or doesn't), but it might be worth trying.

Comment: Try **[Search field](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Search_field_1214696_11.jsp)**, it uses **[KeywordFilterField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/KeywordFilterField.html)** and has support from 4.5 onwards. You can customize [KeywordFilterField](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517065/checkbox-on-right-side-of-text-in-listfield/10522361#10522361) (Subclass of ListField) to add checkboxes [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517065/checkbox-on-right-side-of-text-in-listfield/10522361#10522361).

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I haven't tried for OS 4.5. But it is working fine 4.6 onwards.