# Callback while typing a character in editfield blackberry

Tags: search, blackberry, focus, blackberry-editfield

I need to get a callback with every character typed or deleted in `EditField` in BlackBerry. I need to get the text of `EditField` as soon as it is written, without losing focus.

Comment: You forgot the "keylogger" tag.

Comment: @LinusKleen, why do you assume this is for a key logger? There's plenty of legitimate use cases for this.  Especially on mobile devices, where you don't want the user to have to press any more keys than necessary (e.g. **Enter**), this makes sense.  Or for auto-complete.  Besides, the answer(s) this question is likely to get, on BlackBerry, aren't going to let you *log* keys in any app other than your own.  Not to mention that this is almost certainly in support of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14098719/119114).

Comment: This is a legitimate BlackBerry question - it was closed far too hastily. I am nominating it for 'reopen'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's multiple ways to do this.  For example, if you have an `EditField` instance like this:

```java
private EditField _editField;
```

then you can subclass `EditField` and override the `keyChar()` method:

```java
_editField = new EditField() {
    protected boolean keyChar(char key, int status, int time) {
       super.keyChar(key, status, time);
       // 'key' is the most recent entered char
    }
});
```

or, you can implement a `FieldChangeListener` and listen for changes:

```java
_editField.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        String text = _editField.getText();
        // 'text' is the full text contents of the EditField
    }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I don't know if you can *accept* an answer once the question has been closed, but if there is a little checkmark icon ("V") next to this answer, please click it to indicate that this solved the problem.  Thanks!